# Is it possible to have a Synchronous Post Operation plugin that updates a field on the triggering entity without being recursive?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dataverse, dynamics-365-ce

I'm a beginner at writing D365CE Plugins and have a question regarding plugins that run synchronously, post operation and creates recursion.

I understand that it's the use of the IOrganizationService update in the code below that's causing the recursion when ran during the update event. But is it possible to create a plugin that runs **synchronously** and gets a **post operation value** from the record and updates another field on the same record without causing recursion? I've looked at checking context.depth but it seems to not be recommended due to possible data inconsistencies.

PluginRegistrationTool info:
Message: **Update**
Primary Entity: **quote**
Filtering attribute: **statecode**
Pipeline: **PostOperation**
Execution Mode: **Synchronous**

Example code:

```
public class Quote_SetEffectiveDates : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

                try
                {
                    if (context.PrimaryEntityId != null)
                    {
                        ColumnSet quote_Col = new ColumnSet("statecode");
                        Entity quote = service.Retrieve("quote", context.PrimaryEntityId, quote_Col);
                        int statecode = quote.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value;
                      
                        if (statecode  == 1)
                        {
                            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;

                            Entity quote_Update = new Entity
                            {
                                LogicalName = quote.LogicalName,
                                Id = quote.Id,
                            };
                            quote_Update["effectivefrom"] = currentDate;
                            quote_Update["effectiveto"] = currentDate.AddDays(30);

                            service.Update(quote_Update);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured in Quote_SetEffectiveDates plugin", ex);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("Quote_SetEffectiveDates; {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried:

1. Registering on Pre Operation, results in not getting Post Operation value (obviously).
2. Running the plugin Asynchronously solves the issue (since it creates a new update event after the main operation?), but would strongly prefer to have it synchronously if possible.

Comment: What’s the post operation value you’re using in above code ? I want to make sure nothing is missing in the question context

Answer (score 0):

Since the filtering attribute is `statecode` your plugin is only triggered when that field is modified. It will not be triggered on an update of the `effectivefrom` and `effectiveto` fields.

Therefore it is safe to register the step on the *post operation stage*, in *synchronous mode*.

In other scenarios, where a field is modified that is actually part of the filtering attributes collection, the `IPluginExecutionContext.Depth` property can be checked to determine if a recursive update is encountered.

Comment: I thought so to, but the plugin is still recursive. Correct me if I'm wrong, but after doing some research, I understand the update event like this:
Adding `service.Update(quote_Update)` when the plugin is registered as synchronous will add the update to the same transaction. Meaning "statecode" is included, which will again fire the plugin.

Comment: According to your _PluginRegistrationTool info_ your plugin is triggered on an update of attribute `statecode` only. `statecode` is not part of entity `quote_Update` so the last update will not trigger your plugin.

Comment: Hi Henk, sorry for the late reply.

You're absolutely right. What confused me and made me think that the plugin was recursive was due to the ***Plugin Profiler***. When ***persist to entity*** is chosen on a ***synchronous post-operation plugin*** it causes weird things to happen.

Since this caused the plugin to fire multiple times, I thought they were recursive. But after disabling the plugin profiler and using the tracingservice I could see how the synchronous plugins actually were triggered.